# API request count on Analytics and Number of Record on Installation table

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, analytics

I am using Installation table only, that is all I am doing is creating a record in the Installation table to register for device token, for both iOS and Android Platform.

I am seeing different behavior in the way system is behaving based on the number of API request I am seeing in the Analytics section.

Here is some sample data

287K Record in Installation table

Android - Create Request - 292K, Update Request - 3585157 
iOS -  Create Request - 164K, Update Request - 1116505

I have couple of questions.

1) Shouldn't the sum of number of create request on both the platform be equal to total number of Create Request on the Analytics section?
2) The ratio of Android Update Request/Create Request is around 13 whereas for iOS the same ratio is 7. Why is parse making so many update request for Android.
3) The last question is little bit of side topic - In iOS I do PFInstallation when I receive user deviceToken so I put record only for people who have signed up (and have enabled push notification). 
In case of Android how do I get the same control as iOS, currently when I am initializing Parse it is creating a Installation record, I don't want to do this, because I do not want to save people on the Installation record if they drop out without signing up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major bug in Parse SDK for Android. For some reason it is sending a lot of update requests for no reason. I alerted them 2 years ago, and they have not fix it yet. They said it was fixed in some version but it's not. I filled a bug report here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/102 but they don't answer. Please fill another bug report, we need more dev to alert them about this issue.